# Kafka Connect with custom timestamp.extractor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm having a problem to add jar to the Kafka connect class path, while trying to read messages from Kafka to S3.

The goal is to write messages in partitions based on timestamp, which is part of the Key in the Kafka message.

To make the story short I have to provide custom **timestamp extractor**. Following the documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html#partitioner) created a class that implements `TimestampExtractor` interface and added a JAR location to the `plugin.path` property.

The problem is that when I start the connect, the class is not found. Somehow the jar is not in the classpath and I'm getting

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid timestamp extractor: partitioner.SpotadDateTimeExtractor
```

**Additional data:**

**version**: Confluent 4.0.0

**connect**: Connect Standalone

Starting command:

`sudo  /home/ubuntu/confluent-4.0.0/bin/connect-standalone \
/home/ubuntu/confluent-4.0.0/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties \
/home/ubuntu/confluent-4.0.0/etc/kafka-connect-s3/quickstart-s3.properties`

Aprreaciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make custom timestamp extractor classes available to your S3 connector you will need the following:

- Add the jar with your custom classes along with the other connector's dependencies. Example:

  Save under `./share/java/kafka-connect-s3` if you want this to be
  available only in S3 connector, or in
  `./share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common` to make it available to
  all storage sink connectors (currently S3 and HDFS connectors).
- Make sure your custom class implements the `io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimestampExtractor` interface.
- Use the fully qualified class name when you set the `timestamp.extractor` property in your connector's configuration and of course make sure it matches the package you've defined and packaged in your jar. For instance:

  `timestamp.extractor=me.connectors.MyTimestampExtractor`

Finally, you'd follow a similar process to make a custom partitioner available to your connector.

Comment: Thanks for this, though, can you clarify why the `plugin.path` doesn't work to load the custom extractor or partitioner?

Comment: When you say it _doesn't work_, you mean it doesn't load it from a separate directory in the `plugin.path`? That's because neither a partitioner class nor a timestamp.extractor class are considered Connect plugins (at least at the moment). Connect plugins are: Connectors, Transforms, Converters.